# Trigger Oracle connect database

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

How I can make a trigger that a user connect to database check if user System is connected in this moment. Is correct? Then error message and user no connect to database.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Huh?  Please provide more details. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to point out that it sounds like you're trying to recreate the functionality of the command `ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION`. You might consider just using that instead.

On the topic of your question, there's an easy answer, but it isn't very good.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER logon_system_maintenance
AFTER LOGON on DATABASE
IS
    system_is_connected varchar2(1) := 'N';
BEGIN
    select 'Y' into system_is_connected
    from v$session 
    where username = 'SYSTEM' and status = 'ACTIVE';

    -- this will not prevent users with ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER privilege from connecting
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'SYSTEM user is performing maintenance, please try again later');

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        null; -- system not connected, OK
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        null; -- probably the user doesn't have permission to view V$SESSION! 
        -- should they be able to connect, or not?
END;
/
```

The problem here is that in order to check if SYSTEM is connected, the user connecting has to be able to view the V$SESSION view, which means they need the `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` role. Probably most of your users don't have this role, which means they don't have permission to even check if SYSTEM is connected or not!

In my experience, what most applications do is create a table to hold various system parameters (e.g. `MY_PARAM_TABLE`), and add a parameter which controls whether users can log in or not (e.g. `SYSTEM_MAINTENANCE = 'N'`). Then when you log on as SYSTEM, you set that flag to Y, and the trigger checks that table (which all users should be able to access) and denies access until you set it back to N.

Also keep in mind that you can't prevent DBA users from logging in this way.